# Mongo - Error when saving document: 1 Not primary while writing to db

Tags: mongodb, robo3t, mongodb-cluster

I'm using Robo 3T (robomongo) to connect mongo cluster.
I'm having this error while editing/deleting a document.

> Error when saving document: 1 Not primary while writing to db

I googled for this error, many of the solution saying connect to Primary cluster but I don't know How?

Comment: Did you select Type: Replica Set in connection dialog? Using new type of connection string? Maybe screenshot your connection dialog might help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set connection string of primary cluster like this:

1) login to mongo cluster

2) click on cluster

[image]

3) click on primary name

[image]

4) add primary cluster name as a connection string in robomongo.

[image]

Comment: @eugensunic did you got the same error like in question?